# Во время обновления повторяет последние действия

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee, hibernate, jsf

Создал проект подключился к удаленному хосту через hibernate. Все ок, но вот беда если я делаю действие (допустим добавляю строку в БД через web-приложение) оно добавляется но стоит мне обновить страницу так снова будут добавляться строки, та же самая беда и с удалением. После любого действия стоит обновить страницу будет обратно обновляться проект с последним действием. Выкладываю ниже свой код. Помогите как это исправить. Благодарю

```
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://****/****?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">*****</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">*****</property>

<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="connection.autocommit">false</property>

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">5000</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">1000</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<mapping class="entity.InformationAboutTheDriver"/>
```

вот ревендж

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>  
<mapping class="entity.InformationAboutTheDriver"/>
```

Вот Контроллер

```
package controller;

import entity.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import model.*;


/**
 *
 * @author Elvir
 */
@ManagedBean(name="iatdContrl")
@SessionScoped
public class IatdController {
    private List<InformationAboutTheDriver> lst = new ArrayList<InformationAboutTheDriver>();

    public List<InformationAboutTheDriver> getLst() {
       Employee_dao dao=new Employee_dao();
       return dao.getAll();
    }

    public void setLst(List<InformationAboutTheDriver> lst) {
        this.lst = lst;
    }

    private InformationAboutTheDriver informationAboutTheDriver= new InformationAboutTheDriver();

    public InformationAboutTheDriver getInformationAboutTheDriver() {
        return informationAboutTheDriver;
    }

    public void setInformationAboutTheDriver(InformationAboutTheDriver informationAboutTheDriver) {
        this.informationAboutTheDriver = informationAboutTheDriver;
    }

    public void remove (InformationAboutTheDriver aboutTheDriver){
        Employee_dao dao = new Employee_dao();
        dao.remove(aboutTheDriver);

    }
    public String insert (){
        Employee_dao dao=new Employee_dao();
        dao.create(informationAboutTheDriver);
        return "index";
    }
    public String edit(InformationAboutTheDriver aboutTheDriver){
        this.informationAboutTheDriver=aboutTheDriver;
        return "edit";
    }
    public String save(){
        Employee_dao dao=new Employee_dao();
        dao.edit(informationAboutTheDriver);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Вот данные БД

```
@Entity
@Table(name="information_about_the_driver"
    ,catalog="***"
)
public class InformationAboutTheDriver  implements java.io.Serializable {
 private Integer id;
 private String name;
 private String latitude;
 private String longitude;
 private String number;

public InformationAboutTheDriver() {
}

public InformationAboutTheDriver(String name, String latitude, String longitude, String number) {
   this.name = name;
   this.latitude = latitude;
   this.longitude = longitude;
   this.number = number;
}

 @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)


@Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}


@Column(name="Name", nullable=false)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


@Column(name="Latitude", nullable=false)
public String getLatitude() {
    return this.latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}


@Column(name="Longitude", nullable=false)
public String getLongitude() {
    return this.longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}


@Column(name="Number", nullable=false)
public String getNumber() {
    return this.number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}
}
```

Ну и вот

```
package model;

import java.util.*;
import entity.*;
import org.hibernate.*;

public class Employee_dao {

    public List<InformationAboutTheDriver> getAll(){
        Session s=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
                .getCurrentSession();
        List<InformationAboutTheDriver> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            s.beginTransaction();
            lst=s.createCriteria(InformationAboutTheDriver.class).list();
            s.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            s.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        return lst; 
    }

    public void create(InformationAboutTheDriver aboutTheDriver){
        Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
                .getCurrentSession();
        try {
            s.beginTransaction();
            s.save(aboutTheDriver);
            s.getTransaction().commit();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            s.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

    }

      public void edit(InformationAboutTheDriver aboutTheDriver){
        Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
                .getCurrentSession();
        try {
            s.beginTransaction();
            s.update(aboutTheDriver);
            s.getTransaction().commit();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            s.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

    }

      public void remove (InformationAboutTheDriver aboutTheDriver){
        Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()
                .getCurrentSession();
        try {
            s.beginTransaction();
            s.delete(aboutTheDriver);
            s.getTransaction().commit();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            s.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

    }
}
```

ну и просто Утил класс

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

/**
 * Hibernate Utility class with a convenient method to get Session Factory
 * object.
 *
 * @author Elvir
 */
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml) 
            // config file.
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log the exception. 
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Кому не сложно помогите. Очень нужна помощь с утра застрял на этой проблеме и никак не могу её устранить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это нормальное поведение. Перегружая страницу вы повторяете действие.  С точки зрения сервера нет разницы - это первый запрос или последующий.

Что бы поменять поведение добавьте переход на другую страницу в конце создания или удаления.

Попробуйте добавить `?faces-redirect=true` имени страницы. Вот кусочек вашего контроллера с этим изменением.

```
public String remove (InformationAboutTheDriver aboutTheDriver){
    Employee_dao dao = new Employee_dao();
    dao.remove(aboutTheDriver);
    return "index?faces-redirect=true";
}

public String insert (){
    Employee_dao dao=new Employee_dao();
    dao.create(informationAboutTheDriver);
    return "index?faces-redirect=true";
}

public String edit(InformationAboutTheDriver aboutTheDriver){
    this.informationAboutTheDriver=aboutTheDriver;
    return "edit";
}

public String save(){
    Employee_dao dao=new Employee_dao();
    dao.edit(informationAboutTheDriver);
    return "index?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Comment: а как с этим борроться?как исправть?

Comment: Можете пример показать ?

Comment: я вас не совем понимаю

Comment: @elik Обновил ответ

Comment: что значит  добавить переход ? кнопку добавь или обнавить сделать ссылкой ?

Comment: Можете примитивимер показать ??Прошу а то устал и никак немогу понять .былбы блогадарен !

Comment: обновил ответ. взяли бы вы более удобную технологию для создания веба и не мчались бы.

Comment: Какую млглиб посоветовать?

Comment: моглиб посоветовать

Comment: Grails, Play Framework, Rails, Sinatra, Django, Flask, Laravel и т.д.

Comment: Спасииииииииииииииииииибоооооооооооооооооооо  Получилось!!!!!!!!Пойду почитаю про них !

Comment: Хохо скольок их)

Comment: еще Express, Koa.

Comment: это только те, что я трогал и вспомнил.